# .htaccess mod_rewrite cannot remove page name

Tags: .htaccess

Having trouble figuring out the mod rewrite for .htaccess I want the url `http://www.example.com/archive.php?title=about_me` which is a dynamic url to be rewritten to `http://www.example.com/about_me`. I am using php and here is my current .htaccess code, however it only rewrites to `http://www.example.com/archive/about_me` want the archive to be removed.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/archive\.php\?title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /archive/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?archive/(.*)$ /archive?title=$1 [L]

## Hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

I did get it to rewrite correctly with this code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/archive\.php\?title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /archive?title=$1 [L]
```

However it then returns a page cannot be found error

Comment: I answered below with a simpler form (using `QUERY_STRING` rather than grabbing the same string from the full request), however your intent may not be clear. You've stated that you want to rewrite one URL, but I suspect you really want two - you want the user to enter `/about_me` and have that rewritten to `/archive.php?title=about_me` in the background, but you also want to make it so that if the user enters the "real" URL they are redirected to the "friendly" URL (essentially reversing the above rule). Is this correct?

Comment: Depending on the context of the rule, the starting slash in the second RewriteRule may be causing problems. Try redoing the second rule as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /archive?testing=$1 [L, R=301]` ... this is an intentionally incorrect destination address and uses redirecting just so you can see the final resulting URL in the browser to verify that the rule is actually being used and not skipped. Once verified, then change it to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /archive?title=$1 [L]`, which is what you have above, minus the slash. I always like to test with redirects until I know a rule is being hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want the `/archive/` to be removed, you'll have to ensure that any URI that's in the form of `/something` **must absolutely be routed to the `archive.php`** script. Because there's simply no way to tell whether `/my_blog` is actually a request for `/my_blog` or whether it needs to be sent to the `archive.php` script with "my_blog" as the value of **title** in the query string. The best you can do is check that it's not a request for an existing resource via the `-f` and `-d` conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/archive\.php\?title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
# no /archive/ ^

# condition checks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /archive?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: worked great jon lin and i really appreciate the added information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=(.*)
RewriteRule ^archive.php /%1?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /archive?title=$1 [L]
```

EDIT: Added the final RewriteRule as noted in my comments on the original question. Per the comment I believe you are trying to do the following two things:

1. **Redirect** any user-entered "real" URLs to the "friendly" URL: `http://www.example.com/archive.php?title=about_me` to `http://www.example.com/about_me` as stated in the question.
2. **Rewrite** the "friendly" URL to the "real" URL: `http://www.example.com/about_me` to `http://www.example.com/archive.php?title=about_me`, which was not clear as stated.